# Dissolve identical polygons by boundary lines

Tags: python, geopandas

I have thousands of duplicate polygons, and I need to find a way to dissolve them based on their geometry (and not by any attributes). I'm aware I can iterate through my GeoDataFrame twice and use the .equals() method to identify and remove duplicate geometries, but this method is extremely slow (On^2) compared to running dissolve() based on a given attribute.

I initially created a boundary column, then tried to run dissolve()

```
df['boundary'] = df.boundary
df_dissovled = df.dissolve('boundary')
```

But I got a TypeError. Does anyone know a way to dissolve identical geometries without a pre-established attribute/feature?

Comment: Would it be guaranteed that all identical polygons would have identical "representative points" that no other polygon has? See method representative_point() here: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.representative_point.html

Comment: Would that be guaranteed to be unique? How would we know?

Comment: Yes, you're right, that can work too as long as the coordinates are in the correct order. If they're not, you'll need to reorder all coordinates so they fit the same order (such as lowest to highest latitude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try dissolving by a [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) column:

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/merged.shp")
#df.shape
#Out[13]: (20160, 6)
df["wkt"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.geometry.wkt, axis=1) #Create a well known text representation of the geometry
diss = df.dissolve(by="wkt")
#diss.shape
#Out[14]: (18160, 6)
```

I duplicated 2000 features in a dataset of 18160 features to create a shapefile with 20160 features in it. The number of rows in the dissolve output match the original data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to build on BERA's answer for cases where the geometries are the same, but the order of vertices may not be.

You can use [normalize](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.normalize.html) to standardize the order of vertices so that all of the permutations of the same geometry will have the same wkt:

```
df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].normalize()
df['wkt'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.geometry.wkt, axis=1)
diss = df.dissolve(by='wkt')
```

Thanks to [Robin's Blog](https://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-fix-geopandas-drop_duplicates-on-geometry-column-not-getting-rid-of-all-duplicates/) for this idea.